# R: how do I concatenate a string broken into multiple lines?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Question=c("This is the start", "of a question", "This is a second", "question"), 
  Answer = c("Yes", "", "No", ""))

           Question Answer
1 This is the start    Yes
2     of a question       
3  This is a second     No
4          question
```

This is dummy data, but the real data is being pulled from PDF via `tabulizer`. Any time there is a line break in `Question` in the source document, that question gets split into multiple lines. How do I concatenate back based on the condition that `Answer` is blank?

The desired result is simply:

```
                     Question     Answer
1 This is the start of a question    Yes
2       This is a second question     No
```

The logic is simply, if `Answer[x]` is blank, concatenate `Question[x]` and `Question[x-1]` and remove row `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could no doubt be improved, but if you're happy to use the `tidyverse`, perhaps an approach like this could work?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(id = if_else(Answer != "", row_number(), NA_integer_)) %>%
  fill(id) %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Question = str_c(Question, collapse = " "), Answer = first(Answer))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id                        Question Answer
#>   <int>                           <chr> <fctr>
#> 1     1 This is the start of a question    Yes
#> 2     3       This is a second question     No
```

Comment: I like this solution, +1

Comment: Very nice, and this scales if the question were to break onto additional lines (3,4, 5, etc.) as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following should do, if I follow your logic:

```
# test data
dff <- data.frame(Question=c("This is the start",
                             "of a question",
                             "This is a second",
                             "question",
                             "This is a third",
                             "question",
                             "and more space",
                             "yet even more space",
                             "This is actually another question"),
                  Answer = c("Yes",
                             "",
                             "No",
                             "",
                             "Yes",
                             "",
                             "",
                             "",
                             "No"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)


# solution
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dff, cumsum(nchar(dff$Answer)>0)), function(x) {
  data.frame(Question=paste0(x$Question, collapse=" "), Answer=head(x$Answer,1))
}))


#                                                        Question Answer
# 1                             This is the start of a question    Yes
# 2                                   This is a second question     No
# 3 This is a third question and more space yet even more space    Yes
# 4                           This is actually another question     No
```

The idea is to use `cumsum` on the expression `nchar(dff$Answer)>0`. This should create a grouping vector to use with the `split` function. Upon splitting on your grouping vector, you should be able to create smaller dataframes with the results of the split operation, by concatenating values from the `Question` column and taking the first value of the `Answer` column. Subsequently, you can `rbind` the resulting dataframes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

..another (very similar) approach using dplyr

```
require(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(id = cumsum(!df1$Answer %in% c('Yes', 'No')),
               Q2 = ifelse(Answer == "", paste(lag(Question), Question), ""),
               A2 = ifelse(Answer == "", as.character(lag(Answer)), "")) %>%
        filter(Q2 != "") %>%
        select(id, Question = Q2, Answer = A2)
```